# dynamic onclick, anonymous function with parameter

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, onclick, anonymous

so my javascript is a bit rusty.. 
i am trying to do this:

```
        var images = document.getElementsByTagName("img");
        for (var i = images.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
            var image = images[i];
            if (image.className == "photo latest_img") {
                image.onclick = function() {
                    // here i will perform a different action depending on what image was clicked           
                    alert(image.src);
                }
            }
        };
```

i am just trying to assign a function handler, and that function should be aware of which image was clicked.

if i remember correctly, this was a 2 step process to assign a image handler, and pass a reference of that image.

what's the safest cross browser way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

inside the function use `this`:

```
image.onclick = function() {
    // here i will perform a different action depending on what image was clicked           
    alert(this.src);
}
```

Comment: heh that was easy! so "this" assumes the identity of the owner of the function?

Comment: @SonicSoul no, `this` depends on how a function is called, per-call-basis, not who "owns" the function (functions cannot be owned anyway). In this situation it would depend on how a particular browser implements `onclick` handler calling.

Comment: @Esailija: Not quite true: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind

Comment: in onclick function the this points to the DOM element that has the onclick callback

Comment: @muistooshort I don't see `Function#bind` used here, or it's relevance to my statement. It's still per-call-basis for bound functions as well, it's just that the created proxy function discards it everytime and uses the one in closure to call the target function.

Comment: @Esailija: You said that "functions cannot be owned anyway" but that's not true.

Comment: @muistooshort it depends what you mean with owned, anything can have a reference to a single function and I don't think that means owning the function.